# How to replace image with current uploaded image?

Tags: php, laravel, replace, edit, image-store

I am trying to update image, my code is working correctly but when i upload a new image.
My image path is public\assets\images\uploads\home at this i am storing image

here is my code :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $updatehomeitems = Home::find($id);

        $request->validate([
            'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=160,height=40',
            'image_1' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=960,height=700',
            'image_2' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=960,height=700',
            'image_3' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=1000,height=1000',
            'description' => 'required',
        ], [
            'logo.required' => 'The header logo field is required.',
            'logo.mimes' => 'Please upload an image with a valid extension (jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg, webp).',
            'logo.dimensions' => 'The header logo must be 160 pixels in width and 40 pixels in height.',

            'image_1.required' => 'The left image field is required.',
            'image_1.mimes' => 'Please upload an image with a valid extension (jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg, webp).',
            'image_1.dimensions' => 'The left image must be 960 pixels in width and 700 pixels in height.',

            'image_2.required' => 'The right image field is required.',
            'image_2.mimes' => 'Please upload an image with a valid extension (jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg, webp).',
            'image_2.dimensions' => 'The right image must be 960 pixels in width and 700 pixels in height.',

            'image_3.required' => 'The content image field is required.',
            'image_3.mimes' => 'Please upload an image with a valid extension (jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg, webp).',
            'image_3.dimensions' => 'The content image must be 1000 pixels in width and 1000 pixels in height.',

            'description.required' => 'Please enter a description.',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

       // Handle logo
        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'assets/images/uploads/home/';
            $imageName = date('YmdHis') . $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->file('logo')->move(public_path($destinationPath), $imageName);

            // Delete old logo
            if ($updatehomeitems->logo && file_exists(public_path($updatehomeitems->logo))) {
                Home::delete(public_path($updatehomeitems->logo));
                // unlink(public_path($updatehomeitems->logo));
            }

            $input['logo'] = $imageName; // Save only the image name
        } else {
            $input['logo'] = $updatehomeitems->logo;
        }

        // Handle image_1, image_2, image_3
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $imageField = 'image_' . $i;
            if ($request->hasFile($imageField)) {
                $destinationPath = 'assets/images/uploads/home/';
                $imageName = date('YmdHis') . "_{$imageField}." . $request->file($imageField)->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file($imageField)->move(public_path($destinationPath), $imageName);

                // Delete old image
                if ($updatehomeitems->$imageField && file_exists(public_path($updatehomeitems->$imageField))) {
                    // unlink(public_path($updatehomeitems->$imageField));
                    Home::delete(public_path($updatehomeitems->$imageField));
                }

                $input[$imageField] = $imageName; // Save only the image name
            } else {
                $input[$imageField] = $updatehomeitems->$imageField;
            }
        }

        $updatehomeitems->update($input);
        return redirect()->route('admin.home.index')->with('success', 'Form Records updated successfully');
    }
```

I want a functionality like previously uploaded image should be delete or replace with newly uploaded image.
please say how to change it with my requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $updatehomeitems = Home::find($id);

    $request->validate([
        'logo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=160,height=40',
        'image_1' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=960,height=700',
        'image_2' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=960,height=700',
        'image_3' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|dimensions:width=1000,height=1000',
        'description' => 'required',
    ], [
        // Validation messages...
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    // Handle logo
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $destinationPath = 'assets/images/uploads/home/';
        $imageName = date('YmdHis') . $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('logo')->move(public_path($destinationPath), $imageName);

        // Delete old logo
        if ($updatehomeitems->logo && file_exists(public_path($updatehomeitems->logo))) {
            unlink(public_path($updatehomeitems->logo));
        }

        $input['logo'] = $imageName; // Save only the image name
    } else {
        $input['logo'] = $updatehomeitems->logo;
    }

    // Handle image_1, image_2, image_3
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $imageField = 'image_' . $i;
        if ($request->hasFile($imageField)) {
            $destinationPath = 'assets/images/uploads/home/';
            $imageName = date('YmdHis') . "_{$imageField}." . $request->file($imageField)->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->file($imageField)->move(public_path($destinationPath), $imageName);

            // Delete old image
            if ($updatehomeitems->$imageField && file_exists(public_path($updatehomeitems->$imageField))) {
                unlink(public_path($updatehomeitems->$imageField));
            }

            $input[$imageField] = $imageName; // Save only the image name
        } else {
            $input[$imageField] = $updatehomeitems->$imageField;
        }
    }

    $updatehomeitems->update($input);
    return redirect()->route('admin.home.index')->with('success', 'Form Records updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Copy and paste this code. I add **Unlink Function For Image Replaced**

Comment: @Mohamedrifky Thank you for your valuable time and response. i tried your code that is correctly working for me.

Comment: @KhushbuJoshi. Welcome.